# Sightseeing in the Astral Plane

Tags: dnd-5e, planes, astral

Over the next few sessions, my group are likely to find themselves in the Astral Plane in pursuit of the current BB. They will be level 4 when this happens.

However, I'd like being in the Astral Sea/Plane to cover at least a whole session in terms of combat, exploration etc, before meeting the boss right at the end when they find his mansion on an island.

I've read what the DMG says about the Astral Plane and the only real information it gives is that the Gith live there; currently the party are too low level to really be fighting Gith forces (I know I could adjust the stat blocks, but I'd rather leave the Gith alone for now).

Are there any other known monsters/civilisations/living things in the plane that the party could encounter, fight, get to know, etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that the Astral plane is the major highway between the prime material plane and each outer plane - literally anything could be using that highway: prime material dwellers, Angels, Devils, slaads, githzari, modrons etc. Githyanki are the only creatures described a living on the plane but many others pass through who the Githyanki prey upon.

In general, super powerful creatures have more expeditious means of travelling than using the Astral plane and super weak creatures will avoid planar travel because its dangerous.

So, put whatever you like in there.

Answer (score 6):

Yikes, planar travel at level 4?

Remember,  most of the stuff that they will meet in the Astral is powerful enough to get itself there. Whatever enemies you consider placing onto the Astral, ask yourself **"How did it get here?"**

Most of the things that have a decent answer to "how it got here" will be well above level 4. And that brings up the question **"Do the players have the necessary tools to fight this monster?"** Magic resistance, resistance/immunities to non-magical weapons, etc.

Your campaign may have things working differently, but typically, even just getting onto the Astral plane is a task beyond low level adventurers.

Comment: Yeah, they're following the BB through a portal and I want it to come as quite a shock considering they are low level and probably shouldn't be in a place such as this!

Comment: If you're going to stretch out their stay, advise them to roll up spare characters before the session.

Answer (score 2):

The 4th edition sourcebook *The Plane Above: Secrets of the Astral Sea* covers this in detail.  The lack of 5th edition statistics might not be much of an issue, since your group oughtn't to attempt to fight anything there.

Comment: While this citation may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the citation for reference. Citation-only answers can become useless if a copy of the cited work cannot be obtained.